# Standard mail client on OS X keeps changing

Tags: macos, apple-mail

I want to change my standard mail client on OS X 10.11. Therefore I open Mail's Preferences and change the standard Mail app there. But:

- When I then switch to another application and back to Mail, my standard Mail client is Mail again.
- When I click on a mail link in the browser, the expected mail client is started. When I click on the same link again, Mail is opened again.

To me it looks like something is changing the standard Mail client. The question is what and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a corrupt filesystem. After fixing it with `fsck` in Single User Mode, my mail setting was kept.